# How to stream content with Android's download manager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have an API from which I download data. But this API streams content instead of giving it to me in the form "http://fileAPI/myfile.mp3"
So, all examples I see on the internet about download manager suggest I get the download URL and pass it to the download manager. How do I stream this data ?

Since I haven't found a solution yet, I implemented foreground service with notification to download the data and display the progress to the user.
But this does not work as I expected. I also tried intent service, but still didn't go.

Please can someone help ?

Comment: You can use Android's MediaPlayer or Exoplayer if you want to stream Media directly from the URL. BTW can you share one of the url you are getting in the api you are using?

Comment: I'm not streaming data I'm downloading it